# 18.04: Zoom video conferencing issues only with Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon, voip

Zoom has been extremely problematic for me, after previously running beautifully in 18.04. The program starts fine, but when I try to join or start a meeting, the computer becomes unusably slow. conky doesn't show swapping, and my CPU usage seems fine. Tried updating to latest version of zoom (3.5.382995.0407) but the problem persists.

This appears when using [Cinnamon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cinnamon.1.html) as DE; changing to Unity solves it.

And yes, I did contact zoom technical support but they have long turnaround times at the moment.

Comment: This is probably a problem with Zoom and not Ubuntu. I doubt we can do anything about it.

Comment: I've determined it's a problem with Cinnamon, not Ubuntu. It works fine in Unity.